# OAuth (Facebook, Twitter) and basic login - users table

Tags: mysql, facebook, twitter, authentication, oauth

I want to let users login to my website using their Facebook, or Twitter account, but if they don't have one then to register a new account, and use the basic login of my site.

But how should my *users* table looks like:

My idea:

- id (primary, auto increment)
- username (in case of oauth login => ouath_provider+oauth_id, ex:fb_100001557958700)
- password (password choosed by user or randomly generated in case of oauth)
- name (name to display)

What do you think?
Or should I have 2 tables, 1 for basic login, and another 1 for oauth login? But then how users whill have unique ids?

Thanks in advance for comments.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my experience, you are best storing your authorizations in one table, and your user data in the other.

authorizations:

```
network     - Varchar(255)  #Twitter/Facebook/Openid/whatever
network_id  - varchar(255)  #Users id for that social network.
user_id     - int
```

users:

```
id (primary, auto increment)
name
password
username
```

With this structure, if you want to allow the same user to login with both Twitter AND Facebook at some point in the future, that is also possible.

Comment: in case of OAuth what is the username and password of the user? Is it null, or something generated, or your users must select a username and password every time?

Comment: Ideally you would make the user register a username (which can be autofilled from the oauth provider) and a password.  This gives you a fallback if the user gets locked out of their twitter or facebook account.

Comment: excuse me @Gazler, but what about 'user_id' field? what does it represent in this context? I mean, is it a foreign key to the users table?

Comment: @Atieh this is an old answer, but yeah - it will refer to an identifier for the user. It could be a foreign key in the same database (and is in this instance) but it could be a reference to a UUID in another database. The important thing to note is that this is your reference to the user and not that from the OAuth provider.

Answer (score 4):

This is how my user table looks like.

- User_id (primary, auto increment)
- oauth_provider (enum(none,twitter,facebook))
- oauth_uid
- username
- password
- etc

Every time a user is registering through Facebook/Twitter, a new entry is inserted with the password record as null ofcourse.

I think this is a good way to do it, because you have 1 unique user_id you can use throughout your app/database.

Comment: Thanks dandoen. And what is the usersname in case of Facebook/Twitter registration? Is it null?

Comment: No, when users register with facebook/twitter, they might already have an username over there. For facebook that is the `username` field and for Twitter that is the `screen_name` field.

Comment: @dandoen But the problem here is that only "native" accounts have a password, accs created via twitter etc. dont have. This leads to empty password fields in the db, which leads to potential hacks because username && password == "" (this needs a VERY strong code architecture)

Comment: what if the password field is set to NULL?  SQL's `null = null` comparison returns `false` so I think it wouldn't be a problem?